# Qt. How to view other computers on the network using QtNetwork?

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, qtnetwork

I need to get all PCs IP-adresses in my local network. How should I properly do that if I can using `QtNetwork`? 
I tired use

```
QNetworkInterface::allAddresses();
QNetworkInterface::allInterfaces();
```

but it's definently not what I need.

P.S.

I need get IP's to able connect to some Postgresql servers, is there some Postgresql driver features maybe to make things easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is called "Network discovery". There's a lot of different approaches each dedicated to a specific subdomain. The approach of the lower level is called `ARP, Address Resolution Protocol` see a nice tutorial e.g. here http://tournasdimitrios1.wordpress.com/2011/01/26/discover-your-local-network-with-arp-scan-on-linux/ . If you need a *service discovery* then you probably should go with ZeroConf & friends http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq23-bonjour.html

Comment: Well, I guess I need only discover adresses, because if I got some there's no problem with connecting to Postgresql server there. And thanks, there are nice Linux example but hat about Windows and Mac?

Comment: Well, TCP/IP network stack is basically a BSD (Berkeley Software Distribution) invention and its basic methodology, techniques and tools are the same across all systems. Besides MacOS X is a unix under the hood and an advanced user gets virtually the same operationg environment as in Linux (certainly there're differences but I believe they aren't that important in this case). The mentioned `arp-scan` program is suitable for both Linux and MacOSX. For Windows you may use open-source alternatives like http://sourceforge.net/projects/arpscannet/